# Call an API from web browser to the localhost of Electron app via WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, electron, ngrok

I've made an Electron application as a server to receive API requests on the user's PC. Then I've allowed users to request API from the browser (**not only on the same PC**) to Electron application localhost server. To make it work, I've used Ngrok as a tunnel to publish my local port, but because of the limitation for free users, I could not use it anymore.
I'm aiming to solution calling localhost via Web Socket, but I could not found anyone attempted on the Internet.

Could you please give me some idea to deal with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you do? Having same workflow at the moment

Comment: Currently, I’m using Websocket to resolve these issues. Web connect to websocket, and desktop app connect to websocket as well. Then websocket server will publish to subscribers when have requests.